# Understanding Kli Yakor question on Rashi about Betzalal following Moishe's instructions

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, talmud-bavli, tractate-brachot, pekudei

The Gemara says in Berachos (55a)

> א״ר שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָנִי א״ר יוֹנָתָן בְּצַלְאֵל עַל שֵׁם חָכְמָתוֹ נִקְרָא בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁאָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְמֹשֶׁה לֵךְ אֱמוֹר לוֹ לִבְצַלְאֵל עֲשֵׂה לִי מִשְׁכָּן אָרוֹן וְכֵלִים הָלַךְ משֶׁה וְהָפַךְ וְאָמַר לוֹ עָשָׂה אָרוֹן וְכֵלִים וּמִשְׁכָּן אָמַר לוֹ משֶׁה רַבֵּינוּ מִנְהָגוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם אָדָם בּוֹנֶה בַּיִת וְאַחַר כָּךְ מַכְנִיס לְתוֹכוֹ כֵּלִים וְאַתָּה אוֹמֵר עֲשֵׂה לִי אָרוֹן וְכֵלִים וּמִשְׁכָּן כֵּלִים שֶׁאֲנִי עוֹשֶׂה לְהֵיכָן אַכְנִיסֵם שֶׁמָּא כָּךְ אָמַר לְךָ הקב״ה עֲשֵׂה מִשְׁכָּן אָרוֹן וְכֵלִים אָמַר לוֹ שֶׁמָּא בְּצֵל אֵל הָיִיתָ וְיָדַעְתָּ
>
> R. Shmuel b. Nachmani said in the name of R. Yochanan: Bezalel was so called on account of his wisdom. At the time when the Holy One, Blessed be He, said to Moshe; Go and tell Bezalel to make me a mishkan, an ark and vessels [This is the order in Ex. 31, 7.] Moshe went and reversed the order, saying: Make an ark and vessels and a mishkan Bezalel said to him: Moshe, our teacher, it is the way of the world that a man first builds a house and then brings vessels into it; but you say, 'Make me an ark and vessels and a mishkan' Where shall I put the vessels that I am to make? Can it be that the Holy One, Blessed be He, said to you, make a mishkan, an ark and vessels? Moshe replied: Perhaps you were in the shadow of Hashem [Heb. Bezel el.] and knew!!

So how come the Kli Yakor In Parshas Pekudai (38,22) asks on Rashi who quotes this exact Gemara that he has no idea were Rashi is coming from to say something like that:

> בְצַלְאֵ֛ל בֶּן־אוּרִ֥י בֶן־ח֖וּר לְמַטֵּ֣ה יְהוּדָ֑ה עָשָׂ֕ה 
>     אֵ֛ת כָּל־אֲשֶׁר־צִוָּ֥ה יְהוָ֖ה אֶת־מֹשֶֽׁה׃ ומה שפירש"י שמשה צוה לו לעשות כלים תחילה, לא ידעתי מהיכן למד רש"י זה וכו'.‏

It looks like the Gemara already said so pretty clearly?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the entire Kli Yakar you will discover that he is not asking what Rashi’s source is.  His kashe is that in all places when Moshe mentions the mishkan and keilim he mentions the mishkan first and then the keilim except in parshat terumah.  In terumah (25:10) it mentions an ark first because in that context it is mentioning and stressing the more important item first.

ומה שפירש"י שמשה צוה לו לעשות כלים תחילה, לא ידעתי מהיכן למד רש"י זה כי אדרבה בפר' ויקהל הזכיר משה המשכן תחילה, וכן בכל מקום מזכיר המשכן תחילה, זולת מה שנאמר בפרשת תרומה ועשו ארון עצי שטים קודם למשכן וזה לפי שסדר מעלתן קא חשיב, ואם למד זה מקושיא זו אשר צוה אותו משה לא נאמר כו' כבר אמרנו שאין זה קושיא.

Comment: Thanks for adding context, but this does not really answer the question, that Rashi is quoting the gemara.

Comment: @simyou When Kli Yakar says לא ידעתי מהיכן למד רש״י זה he is not saying he doesn’t know where Rashi learned the source (viz Brachot 55a).  If you read the entire Kli Yakar he doesn’t understand how Rashi can claim that the pshuto shel mikra is that Moshe believes the order should be keilim first and then the mishkan since all places (except one) mention mishkan first then keilim.  You are not reading this Kli Yakar properly so your original question is not valid.

Comment: From the context it actually sounds like he is saying 2 points.1 is that he doesn't know were Rashi gets it from. & 2, is that the pesukim sound like it was the opposite.